# Phonegap app won't reopen after close (Failed to load webpage with error: CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-3

I'm building an app for iOS using Phonegap and I've run into some problems. The app runs fine on both a simulator and real device until I close the app using the multi-tasking shutdown (double tap home button sequence..)

Upon reopening the app I find that it becomes unresponsive and you can't interact with it in any way. I've spent a fair amount of time trying to debug this and I've had no joy.

Error wise I have been getting the error `Failed to load webpage with error: CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1` appear in the xcode console. After lots of googling it seems that this is caused due to hash tags within the URLs (something that I'm using for scrolling down to links both on the same and different pages). Most of the suggestions recommend updating phonegap/cordova to the latest version. I was previously on 2.8 and I went up to 2.9 and it still didn't work, i'm now on 3 and i'm still getting the same issues.

I've checked the cordova git and updated my CDVWebViewDelegate.m file several times with supposed fixes, nothing seems to work. I had a previous version of the app working on earlier versions of Cordova/Phonegap but I've recently upgraded and i'd rather not downgrade to get it to work..

I should probably note that I'm using zepto for my ajax calls and not JQM, for the hash tag scrolling i'm using the following code (figured this may help given it seems to be a hash issue..)

Hash Change function

```
// Ajax
var wrap = $('#contentScroller .scroller')

// get href
$('a.ajax').click(function () {
    location.hash = $(this).attr('href').match(/(^.*)\./)[1]
    return false
})

// load page

function hashChange() {
    var page = location.hash.slice(1)

    if (page != "" && window.location.hash) {
        wrap.hide();
        spinner.spin(target);
        //setTimeout(function () {
            wrap.load('pages/' + page + ".html .page-wrapper")
            contentScroller.scrollTo(0,0);
            refreshScroll();
        //}, 1500);

        snapper.close();
        $(menuBtn).removeClass('active');
    }else{
        wrap.hide();
        spinner.spin(target);
        //setTimeout(function () {
            wrap.load('pages/Welcome.html .page-wrapper')
            refreshScroll();
        //}, 1500);

        snapper.close();
        $(menuBtn).removeClass('active');
    }
}

// check for hash change
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    $(window).on('hashchange', hashChange).trigger('hashchange')
} else { // lame browser
    var lastHash = ''
    setInterval(function () {
        if (lastHash != location.hash)
            hashChange()
        lastHash = location.hash
        contentScroller.scrollTo(0,0);
    }, 100)
}
```

Scrolling

```
$(document)
    .on('ajaxStart', function () {
        wrap.hide();
    })
    .on('ajaxStop', function () {
        //wrap.show();
    })
    .on('ajaxSuccess', function () {
        //setTimeout(function () {
            spinner.stop();
        wrap.fadeIn(700);
        refreshScroll();
    //}, 1000);


    // Local storage scrollTo
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    $('a.scroll-link').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        url = url.replace('home.html?firstrun#', "");
        url = url.replace(url, url+".html");

        var myHref = $(this).attr('href');

        if (url == myHref) {
            var sameScroll = $(this).attr('data-scroll-same-page');
                sameScroll = sameScroll.replace(sameScroll, "a#" + sameScroll);

                contentScroller.scrollToElement(sameScroll, 1500);

        } else {

            var diffScroll = $(this).attr("data-scroll-diff-page");

            storage.setItem("key", diffScroll);

             //Alter value for iScroll
            var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
            value = value.replace(value, "a#" + value);

            location.hash = $(this).attr('href').match(/(^.*)\./)[1]
            $(window).on('hashchange', hashChange).trigger('hashchange')

            // Scroll to element after .5 second
            setTimeout(function () {
                contentScroller.scrollToElement(value, 1500);
                return false;

            }, 2000)

            // Clear local storage to prevent scrolling on page reload
            localStorage.clear();

        }
```

Sample link

```
<a href="IndexOfTerms.html" class="ajax scroll-link" data-scroll-diff-page="First_year_allowance">
```

this will then pass the attr "first_year_allowance" through to the IndexOfTerms pages and then scroll down to the element that has that id

Can anybody shed some light on how I might be able to fix this? It's really starting to annoy me so I'd quite like to get a fix pretty sharpish!

Note: Libraries used: iScroll, Zepto, fastclick, snapjs, spinjs

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [WL 5.0.6.1 Android - Direct Update keeps Native/Cordova resources active/in memory (e.g. BusyIndicator) but reference is lost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623000/wl-5-0-6-1-android-direct-update-keeps-native-cordova-resources-active-in-memo)